# VBA referencing data from another sheet is not working

Tags: vba, loops, with-statement

would appreciate the help here as this is something that I come across a lot when I'm coding. I know there must be a way to do this without selecting or activating that sheet and I really cannot see why my code isn't working.``

WHAT IM ATTEMPTING....Sheet(4) column L contains various asset types, column D contains market values. I am looping through L to sum only market values where "Equities" is the asset type. I then wish to display this sum in a cell on sheet(2).

PROBLEM...the below code only works when I have sheet(4) selected and then run it, but sheet(2) is the one that will be selected before running

WHAT HAVE I TRIED....as well as the below, I have tried `with Worksheets(4)....end with` but same problem

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim EquitySum As LongLong
LastRow = 91
EquitySum = 0

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 12).Value = "Equities" Then
    EquitySum = EquitySum + Cells(i, 4).Value
    
    Else
    
    EquitySum = EquitySum + 0
    
    End If
    
Next
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 4).Value` does not have a sheet reference so implicitly active sheet is used. You could anyway do this with SUMIF formula.

Comment: That worked. Appreciate. Any ideas why using a With Worksheets(4) doesn't work ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, no, but most likely you omitted the dot.